# FTP auto-backup scripting

Tags: backup, ftp

I don't have a proper infrastructure but would like to semi-automate my ability to backup my website from FTP.

My thought was I want to be able to download the entire FTP contents, zip them, and copy this file somewhere... actually my dropbox folder, so the file will then get backed up into the cloud.

Any advice on how to do this, or a better solution, is welcome. **Please note, I am running Windows only**.

Comment: Is your Web site based on a content management system or did you do all the pages from scratch?

Comment: It uses WordPress so the DB can be backed up, but still a dump of the FTP files is desired.

Comment: If you want to backup all WordPress files, incl a database dump to Dropbox, look at Backup to DropBox http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-backup-to-dropbox/

Answer (score 1):

The standard BSD ftp client that windows still includes should be able to handle this.

You will need to write down in a text file all of the ftp commands that will be needed with one command per each line.

Example:

```
open myftp.com
user
password
```

Then you can enter a command to cd to whichever directory you want to contain the backups and upload the file with the put command.

So continuing the above example.

```
cd backups/full
put full-backup.bak
quit
```

Then simply have the command ftp -s:script run whenever you want to do a backup.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are many backup programs that can help you with that task. Personally I have used [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) and I have no complaints. It's free and you can set it to automatically download files from your FTP server to any folder on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.autofilemove.com/ can help you do [this task](http://blog.autofilemove.com/2013/07/how-to-move-files-between-ftp-and.html), also you can schedule backups to Automate backups.
You can backup from/to ftp, dropbox and amazon s3.